# The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state

Tags: mount, windows, ntfs

I try to mount a NTFS partition in nautilus, and it refuse to mount it and suggests `resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting)`, the problem is that I have already disabled fast restart and there is no options to hibernate in Windows 8.

Comment: I don't know why you claim it's impossible to turn off hibernate in Windows 8. The method is the same since Vista (just verified it on a VM): `powercfg -h off` as administrative user.

Answer (score 7):

Try running `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdXY`, where `sdXY` is the name of your device.

Comment: If the Windows kernel actually is hibernated (for whatever reason) this advice would be extremely dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

Its' not enough to disable fast boot. You probably need to disable hibernation completely before creating the NTFS partition:

Under Windows:

```
powercfg.exe /hibernate off
```

Alternatively, try adding the **remove_hiberfile** option, like so:

```
mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile imagefile /mnt
```

Answer (score 2):

When shutting down windows using **shut down** button , hold on to **shift** key . This will completely turn-off the windows .
For more details , read this blog --
https://www.howtogeek.com/349114/shutting-down-doesnt-fully-shut-down-windows-10-but-restarting-it-does/

Thankyou!!

Comment: Thank you for this. I knew this before but it somehow slipped my mind because I expected shut down to... shut down fully. It works just fine now with KDE Dolphin without any config editing.

Answer (score 0):

This happen when "Fast startup" is enabled in Windows. To turn it off, follow this steps:

1. Boot Windows.
2. Search for and open “Power options” in the Start Menu.
3. Click “Choose what the power buttons do” on the left side of the
   window.
4. Click “Change settings that are currently unavailable.”
5. Under“Shutdown settings” disable “Turn on fast startup”.

Comment: The question says “I have already disabled fast restart”.